# Does OpenSSL use given hmac key directly or process before use it?

Tags: c++, openssl, hmac

I am implementing the OpenSSL lib to my code by using the EVP interfaces. But I have a question for secure mac operation with OpenSSL. My choice is hmac-sha256 as mac method. My question is that openssl, apply a process on hmac key before use it?

That operation could be insert any random number or apply the algorithm. For example; it can apply the PRNG on hmac key.

By the way, I am using a version of OpenSSL 1.1

How can I be sure that OpenSSL uses the hmac key directly?